# External Images to greyscale

Tags: php, jquery, html, grayscale, securityexception

I am working on a small project on my university and I met a problem with applying grayscale to externally loaded images from Google's Picasa servers in my banner.
I try to create a greyscale canvas of any image loaded but when trying to get image data i can see Security Error.

I am using jQuery, HTML, PHP and Ajax languages.

Whole project you can find here:
[Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/movable-banner-with-picasa/)

I tried to use this library:
[$getImageData](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/#download)

But i get an information that my request cannot be handled.
I also tried many other libraries and codes but without result.

Comment: Provide the code that gives an error and the error details.

Comment: Where is greyscale.js in that project?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a cross-domain request using the "json" datatype which isn't a valid cross-domain data-type. You should be getting a same origin error. You need to switch to the jsonp datatype.

```
jQuery('.container').ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        url: 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/115131339234962778181/album/jsite?access=public&kind=photo&alt=json-in-script',
```

Note, i also changed the url, don't miss that change, it's important.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json

Answer (score 0):

When you paint external data onto a canvas, it is marked as tainted. Tainting disables your ability to get the image data back from the canvas. However, you should be able to change that behavior using the [`.crossOrigin` attribute](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html)